# Error Handler on the OLEDB Source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a for each loop container and inside that is a data flow. Inside this data flow is an OLEDB source and the data access mode is sql command from a variable.  This component fails whenever the script has a syntax error. is there a way to handle the error so that the package wont fail?

Comment: Share your code other wise nothing can be done

Comment: The script came from a variable and it varies.  :(

Comment: Add an example of the script that fails to your question. That will give people some more context to your problem. You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link underneath your question.

Comment: What "script" is coming from a variable?   I think you are calling something a script when it is really something else.   A script cannot come from a variable.